# Is there an Accessiblity announce() method in TvOS and IOS?

Tags: ios, mobile, tvos, uiaccessibility

In iOS and TvOS I need a function that will speak the text passed to it. Didn't see anything mentioned in the documentation besides the Accessibility label and hint. The text is dynamic and should be voiced on an event so the Accessibility label won't work.

Is there a way to do this?